# How change style of specific element in templated listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox defined as:

```
<ListBox ... ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource User}"/>
```

ItemTemplate is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="User">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Key="Ordinal">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            ...
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Key="Current">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            ...
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Border CornerRadius="5" Padding="5" Margin="0,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource Ordinal}">
                ...
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Now I have an event handler which should set style of item in provided index to "current":

```
void SetCurrent(int Index)
{
    ?
}
```

How to do that?

**EDIT:**

Maybe using ItemsControl will make this easier?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use instead a combination of:

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource CurrentBrushKey}" />
```

and setting SelectedItem of the listbox (better - not using SetCurrent() function, just from logic in your ViewModel)

Hope this will help

Comment: it should be used as a resource of DataTemplate?

Comment: As resource of ListBox i think